# Can't add context menu item to mp3 files (through regedit)

Tags: mp3, context-menu, regedit

Here's how I did it: I went to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp3`, checked the value of `(Default)` which was `dbpoweramp.mp3`, then I created `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dbpoweramp.mp3\Shell\foo\command` and set its `(Default)` to `"path\to\foo.bat" "%1"`. I then expected a context menu item to appear for mp3 files, but nope.

It works for txt files, but the `(Default)` in `.txt` is `txtfile`, so I tried changing `(Default)` in `.mp3` to `mp3file` and did the same thing there, but no luck. It also works for `*` (all files), so I can make the item appear in mp3 context menus, but only by making it appear for all files.

It also works for directories (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest trying `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\audio`

e.g. For creating a custom context menu command to move audio files to a specific Dropbox folder, create the following files.

- `dropbox.reg` (run this)

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\audio\Shell\Dropbox]
  @="Move to Dropbox Folder"
  "Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dropbox\\Client\\Dropbox.exe"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\audio\Shell\Dropbox\command]
  @="C:\\Portable Apps\\Registry Hacks\\dropbox.bat \"%1\""
  ```
- And then `dropbox.bat` (put this at `C:\Portable Apps\Registry Hacks`)

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

  if "%~1"=="" exit /b

  set "targetFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Music\New Music"
  for %%a in (%*) do move "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"
  ```

Comment: It works! Strangely, the only file types I've found that count as audio are mp3, wav, wma, aif, aifc, aiff, au, snd. This despite the fact that several others like m4a and flac have tag support in windows explorer. Also, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3` works.

Comment: @Blrp Kind of late, but as far as I know extensions count as audio/video/etc only when associated with a program that can open them, via file associations. Search for "Change the file type associated with a file extension" from the Windows 7 Start menu.